# Package fontspec Error: The font "Kaiti SC Regular" cannot be found

Tags: fonts, latex

i was trying to write my paper with a latex template. when i compiled it, this file was giving following error:

```
Package fontspec Error: The font "Kaiti SC Regular" cannot be found.
```

I'm using macOS M1, version 11.3.1.
the full log file:

```
./thuthesis.cls:994: Package fontspec Error: The font "Kaiti SC Regular" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.994 \thu@set@cjk@font
                       

./thuthesis.cls:994: Package fontspec Error: The font "Kaiti SC Regular" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.994 \thu@set@cjk@font
                       
./thuthesis.cls:994: Cannot use \XeTeXfeaturename with nullfont; not an AAT or Graphite font.
<argument> \XeTeXfeaturename \l_fontspec_font 
                                              3
l.994 \thu@set@cjk@font
                       
./thuthesis.cls:994: Cannot use \XeTeXisexclusivefeature with nullfont; not an AAT or Graphite font.
<argument> ...isexclusivefeature \l_fontspec_font 
                                                  3>0
l.994 \thu@set@cjk@font
                       
./thuthesis.cls:994: Cannot use \XeTeXselectorname with nullfont; not an AAT or Graphite font.
<argument> \XeTeXselectorname \l_fontspec_font 
                                               3\space \numexpr 3-1\relax 
l.994 \thu@set@cjk@font
                       
./thuthesis.cls:994: Cannot use \XeTeXfeaturename with nullfont; not an AAT or Graphite font.
<argument> \XeTeXfeaturename \l_fontspec_font 
                                              3
l.994 \thu@set@cjk@font
                       
./thuthesis.cls:994: Cannot use \XeTeXisexclusivefeature with nullfont; not an AAT or Graphite font.
<argument> ...isexclusivefeature \l_fontspec_font 
                                                  3>0
l.994 \thu@set@cjk@font
                       
./thuthesis.cls:994: Cannot use \XeTeXselectorname with nullfont; not an AAT or Graphite font.
<argument> \XeTeXselectorname \l_fontspec_font 
                                               3\space \numexpr 3-1\relax 
l.994 \thu@set@cjk@font
                       
./thuthesis.cls:994: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \numexpr 
l.994 \thu@set@cjk@font
                       
./thuthesis.cls:994: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \numexpr 
l.994 \thu@set@cjk@font
                       

./thuthesis.cls:994: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.994 \thu@set@cjk@font
                       
./thuthesis.cls:994: Extra \endcsname.
<recently read> \endcsname 
                           
l.994 \thu@set@cjk@font
                       

./thuthesis.cls:994: Package fontspec Error: The font "Kaiti SC Bold" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.994 \thu@set@cjk@font
                       

./thuthesis.cls:994: Package fontspec Error: The font "Kaiti SC Bold" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.994 \thu@set@cjk@font
                       
./thuthesis.cls:994: Cannot use \XeTeXfeaturename with nullfont; not an AAT or Graphite font.
<argument> \XeTeXfeaturename \l_fontspec_font 
                                              3
l.994 \thu@set@cjk@font
                       
./thuthesis.cls:994: Cannot use \XeTeXisexclusivefeature with nullfont; not an AAT or Graphite font.
<argument> ...isexclusivefeature \l_fontspec_font 
                                                  3>0
l.994 \thu@set@cjk@font
                       
./thuthesis.cls:994: Cannot use \XeTeXselectorname with nullfont; not an AAT or Graphite font.
<argument> \XeTeXselectorname \l_fontspec_font 
                                               3\space \numexpr 3-1\relax 
l.994 \thu@set@cjk@font
                       
./thuthesis.cls:994: Cannot use \XeTeXfeaturename with nullfont; not an AAT or Graphite font.
<argument> \XeTeXfeaturename \l_fontspec_font 
                                              3
l.994 \thu@set@cjk@font
                       
./thuthesis.cls:994: Cannot use \XeTeXisexclusivefeature with nullfont; not an AAT or Graphite font.
<argument> ...isexclusivefeature \l_fontspec_font 
                                                  3>0
l.994 \thu@set@cjk@font
                       
./thuthesis.cls:994: Cannot use \XeTeXselectorname with nullfont; not an AAT or Graphite font.
<argument> \XeTeXselectorname \l_fontspec_font 
                                               3\space \numexpr 3-1\relax 
l.994 \thu@set@cjk@font
                       
./thuthesis.cls:994: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \numexpr 
l.994 \thu@set@cjk@font
                       
./thuthesis.cls:994: Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \numexpr 
l.994 \thu@set@cjk@font
                       
./thuthesis.cls:994: Extra \endcsname.
<recently read> \endcsname 
                           
l.994 \thu@set@cjk@font
                       
)
```

Comment: Can you open `Font Book.app` and check if you have this font installed on your computer?